# D3 Horizontal Stacked Bar Chart with Lines

Tags: d3.js

Good afternoon,

I can't seem to find an example of this and I am by no means a coder but I was taked to develop a living horizontal stacked bar chart with lines. The bottom would consist of 3 phases and the line chart above would indicate how many widgets are within each phase. Does anyone know how to do this or have an example they could share?

Ross

Comment: The two best compendiums of d3 examples are [the d3 wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery) and [Christophe Viau's list](http://christopheviau.com/d3list/gallery.html).  That said, I'm having a hard time picturing a combination of a *horizontal* stacked bar graph with a line chart.  Would the line chart be vertical?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly can't figure out your needs!

Most probably you are looking for like this: [Stacked Bar Chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1134768)

refer it and customize the same! do comment if you need specific help